# iPhone: How to set animation style for UIView?

Tags: iphone, animation

Im using the following code to animate the page.

```
    [UIView a animateWithDuration:0.3
                 animations:^{
                    text.alpha=0;
                 } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                    //some code
                 }];
```

Now I want to change the view using some animation style (curl ripple etc). How do I do it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
        [UIView transitionWithView:superView duration:1.0
                       options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                    animations:^{
                        [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                        [superView addSubview:newView];
                    }
                    completion:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

You might need to set animation transition:


`[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration: 1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionFlipFromRight forView:self.view cache:NO];
    //your code
    [UIView commitAnimations];`

Comment: No I dont want to use this, because then sequencing multiple animations become difficult.

Comment: can u explain bit more what you want?

Answer (score 0):

//try uiview directly or change uiview as your view in ui viewcontroller

```
    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
    [UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self cache:YES];
    [UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

I've correct it to work in alternative to superview:

```
[UIView transitionWithView:self.parentViewController.view duration:1.0
                           options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlUp
                        animations:^{
                            [self.view removeFromSuperview];
                            [self.parentViewController.view addSubview:self.newVC.view];
                        }
                        completion:NULL];
```